# Use VisualStudio for mac on Unity

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to use VisualStudio for mac on Unity?

I tried to set external script editor to VS for mac, but doesn't work.

Are there any another step I have to do?

Comment: There is no Visual Studio for Mac....

Comment: Well... here is it https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: There wasn't one until this year and I heard they were secretly working on it. I am glad they released it but it says "Preview",so there is a long way to go. Unfortunately, *Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Unity* is only available on Windows. Unity support will be supported soon but you can leave a comment [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity) to remind that they should add support for Mac.

Comment: My colleagues who have a mac had to install Windows on their machine since Unity and Visual Studio won't work together properly at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I Think I will continue use monoDevelop.